# Route not found from Angular with Express back end

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to delete all data in my database by a single click.but it gives

> "DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/deleteAll 404 (Not Found)".

Can anyone help with this?

Below codes are my attempt.

Controller

```
$scope.deleteAllData = function () {
Event.deleteAll()
.success(function(){
console.log("All Deleted");
})
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load event data: ';
});
```

};

Service

```
  deleteAll : function() {
        return $http.delete('/api/deleteAll');
    },
```

Route

```
var filesReadUploads = require('./models/readUploadFile');

app.delete('/api/deleteAll', function(req, res) {

 filesReadUploads.remove({},function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.end('success');
        }
    });
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: whether your server is running on 8080 port???

Comment: yea.the port is 8080?

Comment: Please show code where you include this `post` route

Comment: @ kaxi1993 actually i used 'app.delete' in my routes section.i didn't use 'app.post' .I have layered the front end in to controllers and services. and back end there is routes that call the services..above code segments are of those.

Comment: Thanks all..its fixed.it just a written error.the method was right..